# What is the LaTeX code for an "open semicolon"

Tags: symbols

May I know what is the LaTeX code for the following symbol? I can't find it in [`detexify`](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

[image]

Comment: In which context is this symbol used? Is it a math operator, a symbol to be used in text mode?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina As you probably know by now, this is a math operator, the forward (or _sequential_) relation composition of [Z notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation), named after ZF.  I would furthermore guess that it is supposed to be a bold/blackboard type/fat _semicolon_ rather than a 9 with a ring above.

Comment: The `bbold` fonts have a semicolon that looks a lot like this. It is a little smaller than `\fcmp` from the `oz` package. One can access it with the `mathbbol` package and `\DeclareMathSymbol{\fcmp}{\mathrel}{bbold}{\lq\;}`.

Comment: @Dan: that should be the accepted answer, IMHO — the result looks better.

Answer (score 21):

According to [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/), this is a "Z notation relational composition". Looks like you can get it in the [`objectz` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/objectz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oz}
\begin{document}

$\fcmp$

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: output]

Comment: For the interested parties, [`\fcmp` is defined as](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/objectz/oz.dtx): `\def\fcmp{\mathbin{\raise 0.6ex\hbox{\oalign{\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle
     \mathrm{o}$\hfil\cr\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{9}$\hfil}}}}`

Answer (score 15):

This symbol was added to Unicode as U+2A3E.  it should be in the Stix fonts.

The latex name is `\fcmp`.

This name was adopted from a Latex package for Z notation;
the massive update of math symbols in Unicode 4.0 (originating with the Stix project)
incorporated everything from the Z notation complement that wasn't already there.
The Unicode name is "Z notation relational composition".

Comment: I understand the edit, changing all lowercase to uppercase as appropriate for normal English text.  However, when I posted this answer, I was employed as TeX support for the American Mathematical Society, and the way I chose to distinguish between an official answer (on behalf of AMS) and my personal opinion was to apply uppercase only when the answer was "official".  That is not the case here; this was my personal opinion.  You have changed history.  I won't revert it, but *will* mention it.

Answer (score 13):

The best result I've found so far is the symbol `\fatsemi` from the package `stmaryrd`.

When compared with `\fcmp` mentioned above, the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{oz}
\begin{document}

$\fatsemi$ vs $\fcmp$

\end{document}
```

renders as

[image]

Comment: Could you please post some output to make it easier for people to see how it looks?

Answer (score 11):

There's an accent in math mode called `\mathring` that puts a circle over a character. The circle here is a bit smaller than in your example, so it may or may not be what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\mathring{9}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know a pre-exisiting symbol, but it can be rendered easily enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\overcirc[1]{\stackon[2pt]{$#1$}{$\circ$}}
\begin{document}
\overcirc{9} \overcirc{7}
\end{document}
```

I made `\overcirc` a function that takes an argument.

The above code presents always in `\textstyle` size.  If you needed to use the symbol in subscript or superscript mode, the following would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\overcirc[1]{\ThisStyle{\stackon[.15ex]{$\SavedStyle#1$}{$\SavedStyle\circ$}}}
\begin{document}
\( \overcirc{9} \overcirc{7}^{\overcirc{3}} \)
\end{document}
```

The `.15ex` can be played with to adjust the vertical separation between glyphs.

[image]

And if you wanted the circle a different size, putting a `\scalebox` around it will do so.  In this example, I make it 70% of original size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\overcirc[1]{\ThisStyle{\stackon[.15ex]{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  {\scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle\circ$}}}}
\begin{document}
\( \overcirc{9} \overcirc{7}^{\overcirc{3}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on Werner's comment to Thomas (that the symbol is in `\scriptscriptstyle`), it would seem that `\newcommand\znrc{\scriptscriptstyle\ThisStyle{\stackon[.15ex]{$\SavedStyle 9$}{$\SavedStyle\circ$}}}` would do the trick